# Golang wraps a JSON with brackets

Tags: json, go

I'm totally new to Golang.

I can not figure out how to prevent it to wrap JSON in the `{...}`.

So example:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    request, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://example.com", bytes.NewBufferString(`["foobar":42]`))
    fmt.Println(request)
}
```

This example will output:

```
&{POST http://example.com HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[] {["foobar":42]} 13 [] false example.com map[] map[] <nil> map[]   <nil> <nil>}
```

As you can see our array (which is BTW valid JSON) is now wrapped into `{` and `}`. I ran out of ideas how to fix that.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not JSON, it's a "pretty printing" representation of the object, that is only applicable for things like `println` and debug printing. It means nothing and there's no need to fix it in any way.

Comment: As @Not_a_Golfer wrote. Try to print only this: `fmt.Println(bytes.NewBufferString(...))` (insert your json there), it outputs: `["foobar":42]`

Comment: If you fear that this will be passed on to the server, fear not. The server will receive the body exactly as you've encoded it.

Answer (score 4):

It's a pretty printing, see `func Println(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)` Docs:

> Println formats using the default formats for its operands and writes
>   to standard output. Spaces are always added between operands and a
>   newline is appended. It returns the number of bytes written and any
>   write error encountered.

You may use `strings.Trim(st, "{}")` to remove `{}` from string.
You may use `Marshal` and `Unmarshal` for JSON, like this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

type Foo struct {
    Foobar int `json:"foobar"`
}

func main() {
    str := `{ 
            "Foobar": 42  
    }`
    var d Foo
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &d)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(d) // {42}

    fmt.Println()
    body, err := json.Marshal(d)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    st := string(body)
    fmt.Println(st) //{"foobar":42}

    fmt.Println(strings.Trim(st, "{}")) // "foobar":42
}
```

output:

```
{42}

{"foobar":42}
"foobar":42
```